# Android Fall back to ACCURACY_COARSE if GPS in not available

Tags: android, geolocation, gps

I am using the Criteria object to get the best provider like so

```
final boolean isGpsEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
if(isGpsEnabled) {
      Criteria crit = new Criteria();
      crit.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
      crit.setCostAllowed(true);
      crit.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.NO_REQUIREMENT);
      crit.setSpeedRequirement(false);
      String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
      locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 600000, 0, new myLocationListener());
}
```

On my phone (Android 4.1) I have both "Use GPS Satellites" and "Use Wireless Networks" options enabled. Now, the above code works great when I am outdoors and it gives me the GPS location.

But, when I am indoors it does not revert to the "network" provider. It just keeps trying to get the location via GPS and never get its (I wait 1 minute or so)

When I change the code of Criteria to use Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE then it uses "network" provider.

How do I get it to first try the GPS (because it is enabled) and because we are indoor it will not be able to connect to a satellite to then fall back to using the "network". I can't get that working easily. *I state again, GPS is enabled but no access to satellites so want it to get network location instead.*

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was create the location manager and attach 2 listeners to receive updates. One for GPS and another for NETWORK. You set it to receive updates fairly quickly (or depending on your own case, I just needed to get the location)  You then create a method that compares the location of the GPS and Network and find which one is more accurate. You do this at most 3 times to get on average which one is returning the most accurate position and then you stop the location updates.